# Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

What is wrong in below Java code and what does it mean? Can anyone please help me to solve this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.kk.kk.config")
public class AppConfig {
//Define a bean for ViewResolver

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
  }

}
```

DispatcherServletInitializer.java

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses(){
        return new Class[] {AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings(){
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

AppController.java

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showHome(){

        return "home";
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can implement `WebMvcConfigurer` :

Try this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but it didnt help me because WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is already Deprecated from spring 5. @MohammadReza Alagheband